# Database not getting updated from php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sending data from a form to a php script which should connect to a database and then update the table. It's basically a database of all registered users. For some reason, the database table is not getting updated with the values.

The form code is :

```
<body>
          <div class="header">
          Registration
          </div>

          <div class="content" style="text-align:center";>

               <form name="input" action="success.php" method="post"><br>
                  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br/>
                  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br/>
                  Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br/>
                  Date of Birth: <input type="text" name="dateofbirth"><br/>
                  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br/><br>
               </form>

          </div>

        <br><br><a href="index.html" style="font-size: 22px";>Back</a>
    </body>
```

And the php code I have is:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","myname","123","database1");
    $sql="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, age, dob, email) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]','$_POST[dateofbirth]','$_POST[email]')";
    mysqli_query($sql);
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?? The Database is not getting updated. There are no values being entered into my table.

Comment: Check your server logs. You will find useful information there. Check the result of your call to `mysqli_query()`, which will also yield useful information. This is basic debugging stuff.

Comment: For `mysqli_query`, you need to pass in the connection as the first parameter; the SQL is the second parameter.

Comment: putting $_POST variables (or anything else that comes from user input) directly into an SQL command is a very, very bad idea. Look up 'sql injection'. A way around this is to use 'prepared statements'.

Comment: Try this instead `mysqli_query($con,$sql);` and delete `mysqli_query($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, PLEASE use something like PDO or mySQLi's prepared statements.

Secondly, the database isn't getting updated because you need to concatenate (again, don't do this, please!) the values, like so:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user (...) VALUES (".$_POST['firstname'].",".$_POST[]."...)";
```

This is very dangerous though, so I highly...highly recommend looking into PDO.

**Also**
The syntax for `mysqli_query` is wrong as stated in the comments on your post.

Comment: +1 for the warnings. The amount of code I see that isn't properly secured is getting beyond ridiculous

Comment: @Bojangles, we can assume the amount of insecure code has always been appalling -- we just see more of it now, as people share it on sites like StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting curly braces around the $_POST[...]
Like
`$sql="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, age, dob, email) VALUES ('{$_POST[firstname]}','...`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, age, dob, email) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]','$_POST[dateofbirth]','$_POST[email]')";
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user 
(fname, lname, age, dob, email) VALUES 
('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['dateofbirth']."','".$_POST['email']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check for errors when you run SQL statements. You'll never know what's going wrong unless you check whether the query was successful or not, and then print the error.

Also as other folks have commented, please don't include $_GET or $_POST variables directly in your SQL. This exposes you to getting hacked.

Here's an example of the proper way to code this:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","myname","123","database1");
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        trigger_error($con->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, age, dob, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    if (($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) === false) {
        trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["lastname"], 
        $_POST["age"], $_POST["dateofbirth"], $_POST["email"]);
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $con->close();

?>
```

Now if there's a problem preparing or executing the query, it'll report it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create prepared statements is not that hard. Simply copy paste and you are good. I added some extra security with escapeshellarg, which should be more used then it is since prepared statements isn't always 100% secure.

```
<?php
$firstname = escapeshellarg($_POST["firstname"]);
$lastname = escapeshellarg($_POST["lastname"]);
$age = escapeshellarg($_POST["age"]);
$dateofbirth = escapeshellarg($_POST["dateofbirth"]);
$email = escapeshellarg($_POST["email"]);

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","myname","123","database1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$query =  "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, age, dob, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $firstname, $lastname, $age, $dateofbirth, $email);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

Note that "sssss" stands for Strings. If your age is an int variable then use "ssiss" instead.

PS. A simple mistake I had once with WAMP (Apache) was that the user didn't have the right privileges. It took me way too many hours to find that, don't do the same mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Tested

I created a table with the same entries that you posted and have come to this conclusion.

But first; as others have pointed out and it's been said time and time again, the use of `MySQL_` is being deprecated and will be deleted in the very near future. Therefore using [**MySQLi_**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and/or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is strongly and highly recommended.

To quickly fix your problem, you are not telling it to connect to your DB when passing query.

Change:

```
mysqli_query($sql);
```

to:

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

and it will work. It worked for me, therefore theoretically it will work for you also.

- I suggest you use [**Bill Karwin's version**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460432/1415724) for better security.